# Knowing path of a file and then open the file from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I tried finding a file path with `dir` like this:

```
cd C:\
dir test.vbs /s /p
```

It worked, and it showed the directory, but I want to automatically open the file after I find it, so I tried this:

```
 where /r C:\Users *.vbs
```

`C:\Users` is where I put the file, so it shows the file path, but it shows others too.

So I want to use the command like this:

```
where /r C:\Users *.vbs
```

How can I find a file and then put it in my command?

Then the last result I wanted is like this:

```
start "File of a path that has been searched and funded"
```

Comment: I would try with a CMD for loop over files, see 'for /?'

Comment: What version of Windows? **PowerShell** would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are just doing `.vbs` files, you should use `cscript` or similar. Here is a simple Windows batch script that will loop through a directory, and execute all of them:

```
@echo off

REM -- Check the directory where this script is located
set DIR_TO_CHECK=%~dp0
REM -- Great example from Strawberry Perl's portable shell launcher:
if not "" == "%DIR_TO_CHECK%" if #%DIR_TO_CHECK:~-1%# == #\# set DIR_TO_CHECK=%DIR_TO_CHECK:~0,-1%

set "FILE_PATTERN=%DIR_TO_CHECK%\*.vbs"
echo Checking directory: %DIR_TO_CHECK%

REM -- Make sure there is at least one file of this type before looping through a list
if exist "%FILE_PATTERN%" for /F "tokens=*" %%N in ('dir "%FILE_PATTERN%" /b') do (
echo Running: "%%N"
cscript //Nologo "%%N"
)

echo.
pause
```

Assuming each script writes to the console using standard out:

```
Wscript.Echo "Output from A"
```

Output should be similar to:

```
Checking directory: C:\Users\Documents\My Scripts
Running: "Script A.vbs"
Output from A
Running: "Script B.vbs"
Output from B
```

If you want to use the default file association, and simply open the files, you can use `start`. This example blindly opens all the Microsoft Word documents in a directory with their system-defined editor:

```
set "FILE_PATTERN=%DIR_TO_CHECK%\*.docx"

REM -- Make sure there is at least one file of this type before looping through a list
if exist "%FILE_PATTERN%" for /F "tokens=*" %%N in ('dir "%FILE_PATTERN%" /b') do (
echo Opening: "%%N"
start "" "%%N"
)
```

---

A few important notes:

- Using `dir /b` is important. Don't try to use other parameters that change the output (although sorting the list is probably OK).
- You need to single quotes around `dir /b` in the `for` loop. Sometimes it will work without, but if your input contains spaces or other non-alpha characters, the batch script might crash without warning, and you'll be wondering why with no way to triage anything.
- The `tokens=* is important, again for the non-alpha characters in file names. You can get away without it some of the time, but if you suddenly have a file name with a space (for instance, "New Text Document.txt"), the program that used to work perfectly well will crash out of the blue.
- Always use double quotes around `%%N` (or `%%A`, `%%B`, or whatever letter you chose). Again, spaces. They don't need to be a problem, but if you don't quote strings properly, the perfect program will crash, and in the case of "New Text Document.txt", probably give off LOTS of warnings about "Cannot find 'New'", "Cannot find 'Text'", "Cannot find 'Document.txt'".
- You do **not** need to specify `%%N` (or `%%A`, `%%B`, or whatever letter you chose). But you **should**, because otherwise it will quickly become confusing for the next guy -- or you, six months from now.

---

Documentation on the `for` command can be found here:
https://ss64.com/nt/for.html
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for
*(hey, even the Microsoft documentation had a few good suggestions in it!)*

Comment: You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416560/2657515). Topic is only semi-related, but there is some valuable information the undocumented order of switches  
*(hint: `start "" /wait /b <command>` is correct, but the reverse fails without warning)*